# Very Slow problem in Web Application which use LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, sql-server-express

I am developing sample web application which use C#, and LINQ to SQL.  The application is very very slow and it takes about 2 secs to navigate between pages.  I have already used SQL Profiler and monitor the calls to the SQL server.  All SQLs looks normal to me and their execution time is always about 1 or 2 millisecs.

I tried the same application in another PC and it is the same.  So, it is not because of my computer performance.

If you want to have a look at my sample application, you can download at 
http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?rudid9w22id1dmp

The database is under App_Data and you might need SQLExpress 2005.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: I think the proper way is that you cut down your sample to a few lines of code and put it here so we can look at it.

Comment: Take a look at this article (http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/06/24/five-tips-linq-to-sql.aspx) and see if there are things you can take advantage of.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Tracing and see if that helps you to find the bottleneck as it doesn't sound like an SQL issue.

http://www.asp101.com/articles/robert/tracing/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

Are you pre-compiling any of your Linq-to-Sql calls? This does help a lot for frequently used queries, for example:

```
public static class Queries
{
    private static readonly Func<MyDatContext, string, IQueryable<User>> GetUserCompiled
        = CompiledQuery.Compile<MyDataContext, string, IQueryable<User>>
            (context, username) => context.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals(username));

    public static User GetUser(string username) {
        using (var context = new MyDataContext()) {
            return GetUserCompiled(context, username).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

For queries that you run frequently, this is enormously beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL is normal and the calls are always 1-2ms, perhaps it's not the linq-to-sql that's the problem?